# moment.js code doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Found a really good code from jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/ivangrs/zf80q3nh/ for my project posted here on stackoverflow, but I'm unable to see anything appear upon implementing the code after grabbing it from the site! Help please?

Here's the code I copied

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.7.0/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class='time-frame'>
        <div id='time-part'></div>
        <div id='date-part'></div>

    </div>
    <br>
</body>

</html>
```

**javascript.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        var momentNow = moment();
        $('#time-part').html(momentNow.format(' hh:mm:ss a'))

        $('#date-part').html(momentNow.format('dddd').substring(0, 8) + ' ' + momentNow.format('DD MMMM YYYY'));

    });

    $('#stop-interval').on('click', function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
});
```

**style.css CSS:**

```
.time-frame {
    color: #000;
    width: 500px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.time-frame > div {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
}

#date-part {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

#time-part {
    font-size: 2em;
}

#demo {
    background-color: red;
    font-family: Arial;
}

#demonew {
    background-color: green;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

UPDATE: Ive implemented the changes as suggested by @below the radar but the time does not appear, only the stop time button does.

Comment: go to your developer tools in your browser (F12) and checkout the console.. see if there are any errors there

Answer (score 0):

**you forgot a duration for the setInterval function in your javascript.js**

```
         $(document).ready(function() {
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                var momentNow = moment(); $('#time-part').html(momentNow.format(' hh:mm:ss a'))

                $('#date-part').html(momentNow.format('dddd').substring(0,8) + ' '+ momentNow.format('DD MMMM YYYY'));

            }, 100);

            $('#stop-interval').on('click', function() {
                clearInterval(interval);
            });
        });
```

**you forgot the input for the stop button in your body:**

```
            <div class='time-frame'>
                <div id='date-part'></div>
                <div id='time-part'></div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <input type='button' id='stop-interval' value='Stop time' />
```

Comment: no time for the interval and no input for the stop button

Comment: @BelowtheRadar I would like to point out her HTML output is fine. she links to external file javascript.js and clearly states that as well as what's in the .css file.

Comment: @BelowtheRadar I believe that you have finally found what is wrong with her code, but you should keep the structure of her code intact.

Comment: @BelowtheRadar much better ;)